# Making a widget stateful causing hasSize exception

Tags: flutter, user-interface, rendering, interactive

The following page widget throws the exception
`'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
box.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 1965 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
Scaffold

Failed assertion: line 1965 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
FittedBox`

However as soon as I make the widget stateless or remove the FittedBox widget, the run time error goes away.

```
class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyPage> createState() => _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
  String _result = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget result = FittedBox(
      child: Text(_result),
    );

    Widget actionButton = ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          _result = 'Text generated';
        });
      },
      child: const Text('Press me'),
    );

    Widget bottom = Container(
      height: 80,
      color: Colors.orange,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: const Text("Footer"),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: const Text('My App'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            const Flexible(
              flex: 15,
              child: TextField(),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 10,
              child: result,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 50,
              child: Text('Somre data'),
            ),
            const Expanded(
              flex: 56,
              child: Text('Some content'),
            ),
            bottom,
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am encountring a situation where the output result can be upto 30 characters long. I want the result content to be shown on a single line and of maximum size while following the constraints specified by flex properties.

Comment: Why are you creating local variables holding widgets?  Just put those in the right place in the tree.

Comment: I am creating local variables to increase readibility and maintainability.

Comment: You might be looking for `maxLines` or `auto_size_text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to specify a width for the result widget through a container.

```
Expanded(
    flex: 10,
    child: result,
),
```

Update the above code to

```
Expanded(
    flex: 10,
    child: Container(
        width: screenWidth,
        child: result,
    ),
),
```

Where screenWidth is taken through media query.